# Firestore rules are not accepting custom claims from Stripe (stripeRole)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm using firebase-stripe-extension, and I can't get firestore rules to work with custom claims from stripe extension I get this error: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
Is it because the token was not refreshed?
(If I retry after some time it works) => Made me pull my hair out :)

Here's my code:

```
function isPro() {
  return request.auth.token.stripeRole == "pro";
}

function isProPlus() {
  return request.auth.token.stripeRole == "proplus";
}

function proPlusServicesOK() {
  return getUserData().serviceCount < 5;
}

function proServicesOK() {
  return getUserData().serviceCount < 1;
}

function uidMatches() {
  return request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
}

match /services/{id} {
  allow create: if isPro() && proServicesOK() || isProPlus() && proPlusServicesOK();
  allow update: if uidMatches(); 
  allow delete: if uidMatches() || isAdmin();
}
```

And the response from cloud functions with the stripeRole:

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code and text.  Copy the relevant code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  Please edit the question to do so.

Comment: Why are you checking `request.auth.stripeRole` and not `request.auth.token.stripeRole`?

Comment: Old image sorry about that, I updated my post! If I reconnect it seems to work but if I update the subscription and I don't reconnect the same issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, it was an issue with the token not refreshed, forcing token refresh fixed it!

```
this.afAuth.currentUser.then((user) => {
      user.getIdToken(true);
    });
```